# i keep getting TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code :

```
class ClassName():
        q=None
        def __init__(self,q):
                self.q=q

        def a(self):
                print('hello')
clas=ClassName().a()
```

Comment: Note that setting `q=None` at class level is pointless, remove that.

Comment: Consider writing a more detailed question, this can help other users elaborate answers to solve your problem, read this guide about how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you could also add a def __init__(self): to set up a default value, if needed

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass argument to the constructor of `ClassName`, it receives `q` as parameter

for example:

```
clas=ClassName('bla').a()
```